# Laravel $posts += Post::where() is it possible

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I can't get this to work

Its in my PostsController

```
foreach(Auth::user()->roles as $role){
   $posts += Post::where('role_id', $role->id);
}
return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
```

Is there any way this could work?

Im getting the error

```
posts is not defined
```

When i load the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$posts = Post::whereIn('role_id', Auth::user()->roles->pluck('id'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to create `$posts` and initialise it, furthermore you will need to merge the collections instead of adding them.

```
$posts = collect([]);
foreach(Auth::user()->roles as $role){
    $posts->merge(Post::where('role_id', $role->id));
}
return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
```